# JSON redirects to \currentmap\jsonobj

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON string:

```js
var location= JSON.parse('[{"lat":53.230379427401,"lon":6.5237550480959,"couple":"calvin"},{"lat":53.230386732088,"lon":6.5237666455494,"couple":"calvin"}]');
```

If you run the code it will give you a 404 error. I have no idea why it does that or what to do about it. Can anyone give me some insight into this?

I've got this JSON string from the following php code:

```
function getMarkers(){  
        global $row;
        $temp= array();
        foreach($row as $marker){
            $lon = (string)$marker['latitude'];
            $lat = (string)$marker['longitude'];
            $couple = (string)$marker['couplename'];

            $temp[] = array("lat" => $lat, "lon" => $lon, "couple" =>$couple);  
        }
            echo json_encode($temp,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }
```

Comment: Because the global variable `location` holds the URI of the page André assigning to it allows you to load a new page.

Comment: try to use a different variable name other than `location`. Location clashes with  `window.location`. Since you are trying to initialise in `global` scope, this happens.

Answer (score 4):

location refers to "window.location" var in javascript, so its a "reserved" variable name, use any other name to this var and will work

```js
var currentLocation = JSON.parse('[{"lat":53.230379427401,"lon":6.5237550480959,"couple":"calvin"},{"lat":53.230386732088,"lon":6.5237666455494,"couple":"calvin"}]');
```